# How to properly declare a module for React and Require without Node?

Tags: reactjs, import, module, jsx

I'm attempting to learn React JS, and have finally managed reference external JSX from the HTML, but I'd like to have .js / .jsx file(s) to hold common code.  The idea is to have a page specific .js file that calls to a "universal" .js file that would supply JS / JSX.

I added a React.js file as I couldn't find an official HTTP reference for it. and that solved a "required not defined" error, but a "Module name "Universal.js" has not been loaded yet for context" occurs when I attempt to import from the page specific .js.

It would seem I'm forced to build a module so they babel code can read it.
I made a plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PXu15yUsovMacP7R?preview

My specific question is how do I designate Universal.js as a module so that Index.js can reference it?

Code follows:
Index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
        <script data-main="./" src="./require.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/babel" src="Index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Index.js:

```
import './Universal.js';
//require('./Universal');

var vPage  = 0;
var vLevel = 0;
var vDivision = 0;

var App = function() {
        return(
            getLogo(vLevel)
        )
    }
;

var Primate = Monkey();

ReactDOM.render(<Primate />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Universal.js:

```
function (Monkey) {
    return(
        <div>
            Ducks!
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Unconfirmed, but apparently I might be able to declare Universal as a module in the HTML and the following is should be able to reference it: https://dev.to/kirillkonshin/react-jsx-es-module-imports-dynamic-too-in-browser-without-webpack-2pbi

Comment: If I add Universal.js as a babel file, then I get "exports is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, most of my problem was just not understanding JSX / React, but I finally sorted out a way to do this without packaging, which might be without React, just Babel and JSX:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

<script src="./Test3a.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="./Test3b.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<Ostrich />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<Monkey />, document.getElementById("test"));
</script>
```

"Super" JSX:

```
window.Ostrich = function() {
    return (
        <div>
            Ostriches
        </div>
    );
}


window.Monkey = function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MoreMonkeys />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

"Sub" JSX:

```
window.MoreMonkeys = function() {
return (
    <div>
        That's a lot of Monkeys.
    </div>
);
```

}